# How to display multiple notifications using flutter plugin : flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

Here is my code below :

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel notificationChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel',
  'high importance Notificaion',
  'this channel is used for import notification',
  importance: Importance.high,
  playSound: true,
);

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


Future<void> firebaseBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await firebaseMessageHandler(message);
}

Future<void> firebaseForegroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await firebaseMessageHandler(message);
}

Future<void> firebaseMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  try {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          message.notification.hashCode,
          message.data["title"].toString(),
          message.data["body"].toString(),
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(notificationChannel.id, notificationChannel.name, notificationChannel.description),
          ));
  } catch (_err) {}

}


Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseBackgroundMessageHandler);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(firebaseForegroundMessageHandler);
  //FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(firebaseMessageHandler);

  final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('e_app');

  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
}
```

The code is working fine for a single notification but whenever I send multiple notifications to android, it shows only the last notification in the status bar.

Could anyone help me about
how to show multiple notifications in the status bar using the flutter local notification plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group your notifications, there is an option to do that in flutter_local_notifications.
To do this, you can add the following in your code

for ios : threadIdentifier in IOSNotificationDetails

for android :  groupChannelId, groupChannelName, groupChannelDescription,

You can find these in the docs here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#displaying-a-notification  under 'Grouping notifications'.

Basically notifications under same threadId or groupId will all be grouped and shown

Answer (score 0):

**flutter show notification id will be unique**

```
**int id = (DateTime.now().microsecond.toInt() +
    DateTime.now().millisecond.toInt() +
    DateTime.now().second.toInt());**

const AndroidNotificationChannel notificationChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel',
  'high importance Notificaion',
  'this channel is used for import notification',
  importance: Importance.high,
  playSound: true,
);

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


Future<void> firebaseBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await firebaseMessageHandler(message);
}

Future<void> firebaseForegroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await firebaseMessageHandler(message);
}

Future<void> firebaseMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  try {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
         **id,**
          message.data["title"].toString(),
          message.data["body"].toString(),
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(notificationChannel.id, notificationChannel.name, notificationChannel.description),
          ));
id = (DateTime.now().microsecond.toInt() +
    DateTime.now().millisecond.toInt() +
    DateTime.now().second.toInt());
  } catch (_err) {}

}


Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseBackgroundMessageHandler);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(firebaseForegroundMessageHandler);
  //FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(firebaseMessageHandler);

  final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('e_app');

  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
}
```

```
int id = (DateTime.now().microsecond.toInt() +
    DateTime.now().millisecond.toInt() +
    DateTime.now().second.toInt());
 flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.data["title"],
        message.data["body"],
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel!.id,
            channel!.name,
            channelDescription: channel!.description,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher'
          ),
        ),
        payload: json.encode(message.data));
    id = (DateTime.now().microsecond.toInt() +
        DateTime.now().millisecond.toInt() +
        DateTime.now().second.toInt());
```

**Android notification json format**

```
{
    "message": {
        "data": {
            "title": "Welcome message12",
            "body": "Firebase Nodification Success",
            "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
        }
    },
    "registrationToken": "fcm token here"
}
```

This format json is disable fcm notification automatically